# Как выполнить запрос к onion (tor) сайту в .NET6?

Tags: c#, tor, socks5, .net-6

Вот таким образом выполняю выполняю запрос, но происходит исключение `Конечный компьютер отверг запрос`.

Мой вопрос в том, как правильно выполнять запросы к tor сайтам в .NET6?

```
try
{
    var http = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy()
        {
            Address = new Uri("socks5://127.0.0.1:9150")
        }
    });

    var res = await http.GetAsync("адрес");
              
    Console.WriteLine(res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного другой синтаксис.

```cs
var http = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy("socks5://127.0.0.1", 9150)
});
```

Comment: да действительно, спасибо :)